# In class creation, the function call is not answered

Tags: python, class, oop

Im learning OOP functions and I am having problems calling my Plant class. Here is my code, I am getting the error code that name Plant is not defined.

```
class Plant:

    def __init__(self, name, biomass):
        self.name = name
        self.mass = biomass

    def getName(self):
        return str(self.name)

    def getMass(self):
        return float(self.mass)

    def setMass(self,mass):
        self.mass=mass

    tree = Plant('red oak', 1042)
    flower = Plant('rose', 2.7)
    #tree.getName() --> 'red oak'
    flower.setMass(2.85)
    #flower.getMass() --> 2.85
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the indentation of your code as currently presented the question matches what you have in your editor, then you are trying to declare an instance of `Plant` inside of the class definition itself.

Your code should ultimately look like this:

```
class Plant:

    def __init__(self, name, biomass):
        self.name = name
        self.mass = biomass

    def getName(self):
        return str(self.name)

    def getMass(self):
        return float(self.mass)

    def setMass(self,mass):
        self.mass=mass

tree = Plant('red oak', 1042)
flower = Plant('rose', 2.7)
#tree.getName() --> 'red oak'
flower.setMass(2.85)
#flower.getMass() --> 2.85
```

Otherwise, it's a lot like telling the language that you want it to make you a `Plant`, but you haven't finished telling the language what a `Plant` is!

Comment: Haha, such a simple mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Python is particular about indentation, if the indentation of a line is same as the indentation of the line above, they both are interpreted as being in the same block of code.

https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html

Currently your code is trying to create a class object inside the class.
(you cant create an object of class inside that class)
Fix the indentation:

```
class Plant:

    def __init__(self, name, biomass):
        self.name = name
        self.mass = biomass

    def getName(self):
        return str(self.name)

    def getMass(self):
        return float(self.mass)

    def setMass(self,mass):
        self.mass=mass

tree = Plant('red oak', 1042)
flower = Plant('rose', 2.7)
#tree.getName() --> 'red oak'
flower.setMass(2.85)
#flower.getMass() --> 2.85
```